# snmp4j agent responds to snmpget requests but fails to respond to snmpwalk request

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j, snmpwalk

I'm trying to create a snmp4j agent that can respond to snmp v3 walk (getBulk) requests. I managed to get the SampleAgent class from snmp4j library running and capable of responding to snmp get requests. however when it comes to getBulk requests it simply responds with error oid. the logs dont seem to indicate any errors either. I am very new to snmp, any help would be much appreciated.

error oid:

```
  VBS[1.3.6.1.2.1.11.32.0 = 1]
```

which means

```
"The total number of Confirmed Class PDUs
(such as GetRequest-PDUs, GetNextRequest-PDUs,
GetBulkRequest-PDUs, SetRequest-PDUs, and
InformRequest-PDUs) delivered to the SNMP entity which
were silently dropped because the transmission of
the (possibly translated) message to a proxy target
failed in a manner (other than a time-out) such that
no Response Class PDU (such as a Response-PDU) could
be returned."
```

the oid is configured like so

```
        OID oid = new OID("1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1");
        try{
            MOTableSubIndex[] subIndexes = { v4Agent.getFactory().createSubIndex(null, SMIConstants.SYNTAX_OCTET_STRING, 1, 100)};
            MOTableIndex moTableIndex = new MOTableIndex(subIndexes);
            MOColumn[] moColumns = {
                        v4Agent.getFactory().createColumn(5, SMIConstants.SYNTAX_OCTET_STRING, v4Agent.getFactory().createAccess(MOAccessImpl.ACCESSIBLE_FOR_READ_ONLY)),
                        v4Agent.getFactory().createColumn(10, SMIConstants.SYNTAX_OCTET_STRING, v4Agent.getFactory().createAccess(MOAccessImpl.ACCESSIBLE_FOR_READ_ONLY)),
                        v4Agent.getFactory().createColumn(16, SMIConstants.SYNTAX_OCTET_STRING, v4Agent.getFactory().createAccess(MOAccessImpl.ACCESSIBLE_FOR_READ_ONLY)),
                        v4Agent.getFactory().createColumn(7, SMIConstants.SYNTAX_OCTET_STRING, v4Agent.getFactory().createAccess(MOAccessImpl.ACCESSIBLE_FOR_READ_ONLY)),
                        v4Agent.getFactory().createColumn(8, SMIConstants.SYNTAX_OCTET_STRING, v4Agent.getFactory().createAccess(MOAccessImpl.ACCESSIBLE_FOR_READ_ONLY)),
            };

            DefaultMOTable<MOTableRow, MOColumn, MOTableModel<MOTableRow>> table = new DefaultMOTable<>(oid, moTableIndex, moColumns);

            table.setModel(v4Agent.getFactory().createTableModel(oid, moTableIndex, moColumns));

            DefaultMOMutableTableModel model = (DefaultMOMutableTableModel) table.getModel();
            model.setRowFactory((MOTableRowFactory) v4Agent.getFactory());

            addRow(model, String.valueOf(1), new Variable[]{new OctetString("yo"), new OctetString("11"), new Counter32(1), new Counter64(11), new Integer32(1)});
            addRow(model, String.valueOf(2), new Variable[]{new OctetString("howdy"), new OctetString("22"), new Counter32(2), new Counter64(22), new Integer32(2)});
            addRow(model, String.valueOf(3), new Variable[]{new OctetString("wassup"), new OctetString("33"), new Counter32(3), new Counter64(33), new Integer32(3)});

            v4Agent.server.register(table, null);
        } catch (DuplicateRegistrationException e){
            logger.error("duplicated oid ", e);
        }
        //add view to oid
        addView(v4Agent, oid);

        ...
        private static void addRow(DefaultMOMutableTableModel model, String oid, Variable[] value) {
            model.addRow(model.createRow(new OID(oid), value));
        }
```

and the logs

```
2024-02-29 16:06:20.785 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG Received message from /127.0.0.1/51996 with length 138: 30:81:87:02:01:03:30:10:02:03:00:95:67:02:03:00:ff:ff:04:01:07:02:01:03:04:36:30:34:04:0d:80:00:13:70:01:c0:a8:79:00:71:af:e2:79:02:01:01:02:02:0d:99:04:04:75:73:65:72:04:0c:43:21:8a:83:3e:09:bf:55:ff:63:5f:a2:04:08:00:00:00:01:29:13:98:26:04:38:ce:88:5e:f0:17:f0:36:a9:53:00:93:55:d0:67:21:5b:19:4a:26:cb:35:a2:f0:20:8f:a2:00:8c:9d:ea:4e:5f:1d:07:65:d9:71:45:96:80:20:34:be:7b:2d:ed:24:18:5e:2b:c3:37:00:c3:93:ba
2024-02-29 16:06:20.785 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG SNMPv3 header decoded: msgId=38247, msgMaxSize=65535, msgFlags=07, secModel=3
2024-02-29 16:06:20.785 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG PduHandle for messageID 38247 not found in MPv3.Cache
2024-02-29 16:06:20.785 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG getUser(engineID=80:00:13:70:01:c0:a8:79:00:71:af:e2:79, securityName=user)
2024-02-29 16:06:20.786 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG CheckTime: time ok (authoritative)
2024-02-29 16:06:20.786 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG RFC3412 ��7.2.10 - Received PDU is NOT a response or internal class message -> unchanged PduHandle = PduHandle[872645]
2024-02-29 16:06:20.786 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG Adding cache entry: StateReference[msgID=38247,pduHandle=PduHandle[872645],securityEngineID=80:00:13:70:01:c0:a8:79:00:71:af:e2:79,securityModel=org.snmp4j.security.USM@694abbdc,securityName=user,securityLevel=3,contextEngineID=0002651100[02],contextName=,retryMsgIDs=null]
2024-02-29 16:06:20.786 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG Fire process PDU event: CommandResponderEvent[securityModel=3, securityLevel=3, maxSizeResponsePDU=65353, pduHandle=PduHandle[872645], stateReference=StateReference[msgID=38247,pduHandle=null,securityEngineID=80:00:13:70:01:c0:a8:79:00:71:af:e2:79,securityModel=org.snmp4j.security.USM@694abbdc,securityName=user,securityLevel=3,contextEngineID=0002651100[02],contextName=,retryMsgIDs=null], pdu=GETBULK[{contextEngineID=0002651100[02], contextName=}, requestID=872645, errorStatus=0, errorIndex=10, VBS[1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5 = Null]], messageProcessingModel=3, securityName=user, processed=false, peerAddress=127.0.0.1/51996, transportMapping=org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping@527740a2, tmStateReference=TransportStateReference[transport=org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping@527740a2, address=127.0.0.1/161, securityName=null, requestedSecurityLevel=undefined, transportSecurityLevel=undefined, sameSecurity=false, sessionID=java.net.DatagramSocket@73af1184, target=null]]
2024-02-29 16:06:20.787 DefaultUDPTransportMapping_127.0.0.1/161 DEBUG Processing proxy request with proxy forwarder org.snmp4j.agent.mo.snmp.ProxyForwarderImpl@63801ac3
2024-02-29 16:06:20.787 SampleAgent.0 INFO No matching proxy entry found for contextEngineID=0002651100[02], context= and request=org.snmp4j.agent.ProxyForwardRequest[coexistenceInfo=CoexistenceInfo[securityName=user,contextEngineID=0002651100[02],contextName=,transportTag=null],proxyType=1,commandEvent=CommandResponderEvent[securityModel=3, securityLevel=3, maxSizeResponsePDU=65353, pduHandle=PduHandle[872645], stateReference=StateReference[msgID=38247,pduHandle=null,securityEngineID=80:00:13:70:01:c0:a8:79:00:71:af:e2:79,securityModel=org.snmp4j.security.USM@694abbdc,securityName=user,securityLevel=3,contextEngineID=0002651100[02],contextName=,retryMsgIDs=null], pdu=GETBULK[{contextEngineID=0002651100[02], contextName=}, requestID=872645, errorStatus=0, errorIndex=10, VBS[1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5 = Null]], messageProcessingModel=3, securityName=user, processed=false, peerAddress=127.0.0.1/51996, transportMapping=org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping@527740a2, tmStateReference=TransportStateReference[transport=org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping@527740a2, address=127.0.0.1/161, securityName=null, requestedSecurityLevel=undefined, transportSecurityLevel=undefined, sameSecurity=false, sessionID=java.net.DatagramSocket@73af1184, target=null]]]
2024-02-29 16:06:20.787 SampleAgent.0 DEBUG Removed msgId retry cache sub-entry: 38247 from msgIdToPduHandleMapping: PduHandle[872645]
2024-02-29 16:06:20.788 SampleAgent.0 DEBUG Removed cache entry: StateReference[msgID=38247,pduHandle=null,securityEngineID=80:00:13:70:01:c0:a8:79:00:71:af:e2:79,securityModel=org.snmp4j.security.USM@694abbdc,securityName=user,securityLevel=3,contextEngineID=0002651100[02],contextName=,retryMsgIDs=null] for PduHandle[872645]
2024-02-29 16:06:20.788 SampleAgent.0 DEBUG Removed cache entry on getEntry: StateReference[msgID=38247,pduHandle=PduHandle[872645],securityEngineID=80:00:13:70:01:c0:a8:79:00:71:af:e2:79,securityModel=org.snmp4j.security.USM@694abbdc,securityName=user,securityLevel=3,contextEngineID=0002651100[02],contextName=,retryMsgIDs=null] for msgID 38247
2024-02-29 16:06:20.788 SampleAgent.0 DEBUG RFC3414 ��3.1.4.a Outgoing message needs to be encrypted
2024-02-29 16:06:20.788 SampleAgent.0 DEBUG Preparing decrypt_params.
2024-02-29 16:06:20.788 SampleAgent.0 DEBUG Preparing iv for encryption.
2024-02-29 16:06:20.788 SampleAgent.0 DEBUG Encryption finished.
2024-02-29 16:06:20.788 SampleAgent.0 DEBUG Sending message to 127.0.0.1/51996 from 127.0.0.1/161 with length 129: 30:7f:02:01:03:30:10:02:03:00:95:67:02:03:00:ff:ff:04:01:03:02:01:03:04:36:30:34:04:0d:80:00:13:70:01:c0:a8:79:00:71:af:e2:79:02:01:01:02:02:0d:99:04:04:75:73:65:72:04:0c:18:c1:52:a5:62:cc:88:fa:03:3c:d5:b5:04:08:00:00:00:01:d4:92:15:49:04:30:51:3c:5d:46:07:b1:1d:b9:67:62:b0:af:85:fa:24:2c:8e:3e:88:d1:7d:8c:5e:e1:d7:3d:77:da:f7:d0:c8:b4:59:ef:04:54:48:d2:d2:a5:0d:f7:9f:d0:06:d7:6d:70
2024-02-29 16:06:20.788 SampleAgent.0 DEBUG Sending packet to 127.0.0.1/51996
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.

turns out the agent is fine, its the manager thats the problem.

manager was setting context engine id in the pdu when walking which was causing the agent to look for a proxy agent that doesn't exist...

removing that and everything works